# How do I save data in my current activity so that i can access it next time on same activity Android?

Tags: android

i have a listview in which i have some list of data i am sending it to other activity on click

**i am sending data with intent**

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AppDiscription.class);
                    i.putExtra("NAME", s);
                    i.putExtra("AMT", Appname);
                    i.putExtra("COUNT", cnvert);
                    i.putExtra("SELECTEDID", selectedFromList);
                    startActivity(i);
```

**on receiving activity:**

```
if (extras != null) {

            Appname = extras.getString("NAME");
            total = extras.getString("AMT");
            count = extras.getString("COUNT");
            selected = extras.getString("SELECTEDID");
}
```

now i have to save "**selected**" into a variable on this activity so that i can compare it with new "**selected**" data which will came with next intent when i will click on listview.

Comment: I'd use sharedpreferences: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3624358/508126

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//inside onCreate()

```
SharedPreferences  preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE); 
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
```

//reading last saved selectedID

```
lastSavedSelected = preferences.getString("selectedID", "defaultID");
```

//saving new selectedID

```
editor.putString("selectedID", selected); 
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an ArrayList and add all the **selected** strings as they come. And compare this way:

```
list.get(last) == list.get(last-1);
```

but if you are interested in comparing only the previous and the newly created value.

use **sharedprefrence**

Answer (score 0):

How do you get your "extras" object? It is a bundle from the activity's intent, right?

```
 final Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();
```

Comment: Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

Comment: what is the problem more precisely? the extras object is null or simply empty?

Comment: but i want to store it as a variable for this activity.

Comment: no they are not empty i am getting data but want to store it on this activity.so that i can compare it with next intent data

Comment: aha, sorry, i misunderstood, i thought you had a problem in passing the data, in this case you could use a queue, add the item, compare,poll...